# Windows updates - check for installed KB / CVE patching

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Sorry if this sounds stupid but I really couldn't figure out how to proceed efficiently.

I have a Windows 10 client that I wanted to verify it is patched against known vulnerabilities, e.g. CVE-2019-1484.

What I did so far:

1. Went to [MS security update guide for CVE-2019-1484](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2019-1484), read there that KB4530684 should patch my Windows 10 1903 x64 system.
2. Looked up the installed KBs on the client with `wmic qfe list` and found that KB4530684 isn't listed.
3. Checked for newer KBs that meanwhile are replacing KB4530684 in the [MS update catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4530684) where the [details](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=23df10e6-4bbe-4879-b964-a764873d48f4) for my specific client shows that there are meanwhile 18 different KBs that are replacing KB4530684, one of them being KB4574727 which is installed on my client.

Now here's the actual question:
Is there a way I can do this more efficiently? I struggle to imagine that browsing through the MS website manually is the most efficient way for checking CVE patch coverage.

Comment: If you keep Windows up to date, the updates will do the required patching for you. All automatic that way.

Comment: @John: I'm aware of that, or at least that it should be that way if everything works as it should. However, I would really appreciate if there's a way to do the checking myself in an automated fashion that works without manual (not too user-friendly built) MS website browsing; in-site searching etc. It is fine for a single check of CVE patch coverage, but for broader checks it's just requiring to spend an extreme amount of time for someting that simple..

Comment: Truly I do not know any way to do that. What you are trying to automate is your own version of Automatic Updates and I think Windows just has the way it offers for us.